# How do I show something after mouseover longer than 1 second with jQuery QTip

Tags: jquery, mouseover, show, qtip

I want to display a QTIP (http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) after my mouseover is longer then 1 second on a link. how is this possible?

If im with the mouse over the element less then 1 second, nothing should happen.
I have tried the below code, but my browser crashes:

```
$(".Details").bind("mouseover", function() 
{
  t= setTimeout($(this).qtip({ args... }), 1000); });
  $(".Details").bind("mouseout", function() { clearTimeout(t); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In the mouseover event, set a timeout for a second. In the mouseout event, cancel the timeout. In the timeout function, display your qtip.

Comment: i tried it, but my browser crashes :S
whats wrong?

    $(".Details").bind("mouseover", function() {
       t= setTimeout($(this).qtip({
            args...
        }), 1000);
    });
    $(".Details").bind("mouseout", function() {
        clearTimeout(t);
    });

Comment: It can be tricky to figure out where to store the data; a global variable might not work as well if you have multiple instances. Try using element data: `$(".Details").bind("mouseover", function (e) { var me = this; $(this).data("qtip", setTimeout(function () { $(me).qtip({args...}); }, 1000)); });` and `$(".Details").bind("mouseout", function (e) { clearTimeout($(this).data("qtip"));`. However, I think that the real answer might be the one from bendewey before; I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Set the [`show.delay`](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/#show) property on the qTip plugin.

```
$(function() {
  $('#myDiv').qtip({
    content: 'My tooltip',
    show: { delay: 1000 }
  });

});
```

Comment: No, i tried that.
the problem is, it shows it even im not hovered more than 1 second!

Comment: in your sample your binding to mouseover/out, you should be able to just have my code on the top of your page.

Comment: what if i only need the delay onmouseover, but not onClick?